# Data scrape Python beautifulsoup code do not loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am trying to scrape data. Somehow the loop doesn't work correctly. It loops just once. I want to scrape all the name of the goods and the price.

The goods are inside "td" eg : "Sendok Semen 7 Bulat" and the price are inside "div" eg : "8.500"

Here is my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.ralali.com/search/semen'
res = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
#divs = html.find_all('div', class_ = "col-md-12 col-xs-12") 
divs = html.findAll('div', class_ = "row d-block")
cnt = 0

for div in divs:
  cnt += 1
  #print(div, end="\n"*2)
  price = div.find('span', class_ = 'float-right')
  print(price.text.strip())
  print(cnt)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: whats the length of `divs` ?

Comment: do you want to scrap the "List Of Popular Semen Prices In Ralali" or all products ?

Comment: print(len(divs)) gives 1.

Comment: @Midoki I want to scrap all products

Comment: I tried with full page scraping. I didnt get the data in the html object itself. It may be beautifulsoup's issue.. you may try xpath..

Comment: https://medium.com/@nsvtransports/a-simple-way-to-scrape-indeed-com-review-page-xpath-vs-beautifulsoup4-f61e49a3c541

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar if i print the "divs", it gets all the texts correctly. I just can not scrape all the values inside some tags, only 1 is scraped.

Comment: @PrasatyoPartTwo when you print the div you get the table of "List Of Popular Semen Prices In Ralali" and not all the the products listed in the web page. You can't get the products using BeautifulSoup because is being created by JavaScript, and  `requests` can't handle dynamically generated elements by JavaScript. you can use selenium to do that.

Comment: @Midoki have you tried printing the "div" ? All the texts are there... Does it mean that if all the texts got pulled out, they should be able to be extracted ? And why it can extract one of the value ?

Comment: @Midoki You might be correct. I think the content is being dynamically generated by js. What my "div" print is the view of "List Of Popular Semen Prices In Ralali", which is only 10. please confirm on this because i will move on to selenium. thanks

Comment: @PrasatyoPartTwo yes the content is dynamically generated and you can't fetch it using beautifulsoup4, you should use selenium or another tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

> Somehow the loop doesn't work correctly. It loops just once.

It is not the loop that won't work correctly, it is rather the way you are selecting things. So `html.findAll('div', class_ = "row d-block")` will find only one `<div>` that matches your criteria.

#### How to fix?

Make you are selecting more specific, cause what you are really want to iterate are the `<tr>` in the table - I often use `css selectors` and the following will get the correct selection, so just replace your `html.findAll('div', class_ = "row d-block")` **Note** In new code use `find_all()` instead of `findAll()` it is the newer syntax:

```
html.select('.d-block tbody tr')
```

#### Example

Will give you a well structured list of dicts:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.ralali.com/search/semen'
res = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")

data = []
for row in html.select('.d-block tbody tr'):
    data.append(
        dict(
            zip(['pos','name','currency','price'],list(row.stripped_strings))
        )
    )
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'pos': '1',
  'name': 'Sendok Semen 7 Bulat',
  'currency': 'Rp',
  'price': '8.500'},
 {'pos': '2',
  'name': 'Sendok Semen 8 Bulat Gagang Kayu',
  'currency': 'Rp',
  'price': '10.000'},
 {'pos': '3', 'name': 'SEMEN', 'currency': 'Rp', 'price': '10.000'},
 {'pos': '4',
  'name': 'Sendok Semen 8 Gagang Kayu SWARDFISH',
  'currency': 'Rp',
  'price': '10.000'},...]
```

### But Be Aware

It will just help you to get the Top 10 - List Of Popular Semen Prices In Ralali and not all goods and prices on the page --> That is something you should clarify in your question.

## Getting more data from all products

#### Option#1

Use an api that is provided by the website and iterate by parameter pages:

```
import requests

url = 'https://rarasearch.ralali.com/v2/search/item?q=semen'
res = requests.get(url)

data = []

for p in range(1, round(res.json()['total_item']/20)):
    url = f'https://rarasearch.ralali.com/v2/search/item?q=semen&p={p}'
    res = requests.get(url)
    data.extend(res.json()['items'])

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 114797,
  'name': 'TIGA RODA Semen NON semen putih',
  'image': 'assets/img/Libraries/114797_TIGA_RODA_Semen_NON_semen_putih_1_UrwztohXHo9u1yRY_1625473149.png',
  'alias': 'tiga-roda-semen-non-semen-putih-157561001',
  'vendor_id': 21156,
  'vendor_alias': 'prokonstruksi',
  'rating': '5.00',
  'vendor_status': 'A',
  'vendor_name': 'Pro Konstruksi',
  'vendor_location': 'Palembang',
  'price': '101500.00',
  'discount': 0,
  'discount_percentage': 0,
  'free_ongkir_lokal': 0,
  'free_ongkir_nusantara': 1,
  'is_stock_available': 1,
  'minimum_order': 1,
  'maximum_order': 999999999,
  'unit_type': 'unit',
  'ss_type': 0,
  'is_open': 'Y',
  'wholesale_price': []},
 {'id': 268711,
  'name': 'Sendok Semen Ukuran 6',
  'image': 'assets/img/Libraries/268711_Sendok-Semen-Ukuran-6_HCLcQq6TUh5IiEPZ_1553521818.jpeg',
  'alias': 'Sendok-Semen-Ukuran-6',
  'vendor_id': 305459,
  'vendor_alias': 'distributorbangunan',
  'rating': None,
  'vendor_status': 'A',
  'vendor_name': 'Distributor Bangunan',
  'vendor_location': 'Bandung',
  'price': '11000.00',
  'discount': 0,
  'discount_percentage': 0,
  'free_ongkir_lokal': 0,
  'free_ongkir_nusantara': 0,
  'is_stock_available': 1,
  'minimum_order': 1,
  'maximum_order': 999999999,
  'unit_type': 'Unit',
  'ss_type': 0,
  'is_open': 'Y',
  'wholesale_price': []},...]
```

#### Option#2

Use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#), scroll to the bottom of the page toa load all products, push the `driver.page_source` to your `soup` and start selecting, ...